# Is that a valid XPath?

Tags: xpath, xsd

I'm using Oxygen to generate XPaths for my project. However, sometimes XPath ,that Oxygen gives me, is like
`/element(*,SituationSummaryType)/weatherEffects/ct:METARReadings/ct:stationID` .
 It looks meaningful(basically says among all the elements of SituationSummaryType get me blabla) but I'm not sure about `/element(*,SituationSummaryType)` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/#id-element-test), it tests for an element with any name of type `SituationSummaryType`.

Answer (score 3):

It's valid in XPath 2.0 but not in XPath 1.0.

In XPath 2.0, it will only work if you have a schema-aware XPath processor and if you run it against a schema-validated source document. In this context `element(*,SituationSummaryType)` matches an element node with any name (`*`) that has been validated against the XSD type `SituationSummaryType`.